# Is there a MySQL engine for in-memory tables that support row locks?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

The default MySQL in-memory engine only supports table-locks. This is killing our performance on our session table (using Joomla on the front-end).

Is there a (third-party) engine of an in-memory table that supports row-based locking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ndb's memory engine does row-level locking:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html
I'm not aware of any other plugin that does.

Have you considered using tmpfs or ramfs for storage?